# Как люди могут пользоваться моим образом Docker?

Tags: docker, веб-сервер

После команды

```
docker compose build
```

у меня, как я понял собрался образ. На этом образе у меня веб-сервис, к которому можно обратиться по локальной сети.

Я хочу, чтобы те люди, у которых был бы мой образ, могли его запустить на своем компьютере в Windows, чтобы они пользовались моим веб-сервисом в своей локальной сети.

**Как обычному пользователю подключиться к моему образу Docker, сделав минимально для этого усилий?**

Comment: образ можно залить на docker hub, а пользователь сможет его потом скачать и запустить

Comment: а как мне найти этот образ на компе?

Comment: Не нужно его находить. Нужно ему дать провильный тег и выполнить команду `docker push`. Читайте https://docs.docker.com/docker-hub/